# Weird behavior while subclassing CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, subclass

i have this:

```
//Node.h

 @interface Node: CCSprite{
 BOOL wasTouched;
 }
 -(BOOL)getTouched;
 // some other methods

 //Node.m

 -(BOOL)getTouched{
 return wasTouched;
 }

-(id)init{
    wasTouched=NO;
    }

//wasTouched changes in the other methods..when they are called (no problem here)


//Game.m

//i make an array of nodes and do some stuff

-(void)someMethod{
    for (Node *node in arrayOfNodes){
    if ([node getTouched]) {  //here it crashes
    //code
    }}}
```

it crashes with message `-[CCSprite getTouched]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x236dd0`

the question is: WHY?!

Comment: How do you receive the `arrayOfNodes` and can you confirm that in really contains only `Node` objects and no `CCSprite`?

Comment: i create a random array of nodes in the init method of Game, and i've checked, the other custom methods work..only this doesn't. I'm trying to rewrite my code to get around this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably inserted a plain CCSprite in your Nodes array.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id)init{
    wasTouched=NO;
    }
```

**This hurts. :(**

You always have to call the super implementation of an init method. You also have to return self here. Did the compiler not complain about a missing return value? Word of advice: do not ignore compiler warnings.

Both of this can lead to very weird behavior, including crashes I guess. Here's the fix:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        wasTouched = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: well i am..this is obviously not the full code...anyway..i made a work-around and it seems to be ok now